# Is addition definable from successor and multiplication?

Tags: model-theory, natural-numbers

Consider the structure $(\mathbb{N};\times,S,0,1)$, where $\times$ represents multiplication and $S$ represents successor. Is the addition function definable by a first-order formula in that structure? That is, is there a first order formula with three free variables $x,y,z$ such that the formula holds iff $x+y=z$?