# Is addition a term-function in this structure?

Tags: model-theory, natural-numbers, universal-algebra

This is a follow-up to my previous model theory question, here: [Is addition definable from successor and multiplication?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4886153/is-addition-definable-from-successor-and-multiplication). I asked whether addition is definable by a first-order formula in the structure $(\mathbb{N};\times,S,0,1)$ in that question, and found that that question was asked previously. However, now I have a different question. Is addition a term function in that structure? A term function is a function composed from projection functions and the functions and constants that are in the structure. I think it isn't, but I want a proof that it is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not.

Suppose $t$ is a term such that $t(x,y)\equiv x+y$. WLOG we may assume that $t$ has no instance of "$0\times$" or "$\times 0$" occurring in it. Clearly both variables $x$ and $y$ must actually occur in $t$. But now we can show by induction on complexity that $\forall x,y[t(x,y)\ge xy]$, which isn't true for $x+y$.